# Is it necessary to use SSIS to create SSAS cubes using Oracle data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas, business-intelligence

I'm working on research project using Microsoft BI Stack and Oracle Database. When working with these two technologies I was able to use SSIS and SSRS.

My process was connecting Oracle database through SSIS and SSAS.

Yes, it has worked but SSIS is responsible for the ETL process. I was still able to create cubes in SSAS without using SSIS.

What's the difference between these two processes?

1. When using SSAS without SSIS, is it automatically invoking the SSIS process (ETL) behind the scenes?
2. If yes, what's the point of having SSIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSIS is an ETL framework, which means it is designed to EXTRACT, TRANSFORM and LOAD data from one or multiple sources to one or multiple destinations.

SSAS is an OLAP (online analytical processing) that is designed to aggregate data from one or multiple sources for faster multi dimensional queries.

Both tools CAN be used together in the sense that SSIS can be used to build a datawarehouse on which SSAS will be building it's cubes, but in no way they are dependant.

You can also use SSIS to process your cube automatically (either full or partial).

To answer more clearly your questions : No, SSAS does not invoke SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can build cubes in SSAS directly against Oracle Data. Avoid SSIS entirely.. although most people prefer to copy the data into MS SQL because MS SQL is CHEAPER than Oracle.